# Declaration of a abstract generic type variable

Tags: c#, generics, abstract-class

my problem is the following. I have made a code design for a home project which is apparently not working. Maybe you can help me to figure out where the "code smell" comes from.

Ok let's start:
I have defined some classes to wrap around different kind of archive types:

```
public abstract class Archive { }
public class ZipArchive : Archive { }
public class TarArchive : Archive { }
```

To handle with those archives, I defined Manager classes. 
An abstract one that defines the needed behaviour,

```
public abstract class ArchiveManager<T> where T : Archive
{ 
    public abstract void OpenArchive(T archive);
}
```

And the concrete ones, that actually implement the specific behaiour:

```
public class ZipArchiveManager : ArchiveManager<ZipArchive>
{
    public override void OpenArchive(ZipArchive archive) {  /* .. */ }
}

public class TarArchiveManager : ArchiveManager<TarArchive>
{
    public override void OpenArchive(TarArchive archive) {  /* .. */ }
}
```

What happens now is that during compile time, I dont know which kind of archives I will process, so I tried the following:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ArchiveManager<Archive> archiveManager = null;

        if (/*some condition*/) {            
            archiveManager = new ZipArchiveManager();
        }
        else {
            archiveManager = new TarArchiveManager();
        }
    }
}
```

which ended up in the following error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'ZipArchiveManager' to
>   'ArchiveManager'

As far as I understand, the generic argument cannot be implicitely converted. Is there any way to come around this? Does this code / design "smell"?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Create a non generic base class, or use a covariant interface.

Comment: Also, the signature of `OpenArchive` looks wrong to me. Shouldn't it receive a stream, and return `T`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a contravariant interface instead of an abstract class that doesn't implement any functionality. In this case, you can only use the type parameter as a return value of a method, not as an argument:

```cs
public interface IArchiveManager<out T>
    where T : Archive
{
    T OpenArchive(Stream stream);
}
```

Then, simply implement the interface in your manager classes:

```cs
public class ZipArchiveManager : IArchiveManager<ZipArchive>
{
    public ZipArchive OpenArchive(Stream stream)
    {
        // ...
    }
}

public class TarArchiveManager : IArchiveManager<TarArchive>
{
    public TarArchive OpenArchive(Stream stream)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answers. Contravariant interface seem to be the only way to overcome this. However I believe I have to re-think my architecture as a whole... :(

Answer (score 0):

I found another way by using the "dynamic" keyword of c# .NET 4.0...

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        dynamic archiveManager = null;

        if (/*some condition*/) {            
            archiveManager = new ZipArchiveManager();
        }
        else {
            archiveManager = new TarArchiveManager();
        }
    }
}
```

Works like a charm for me ;)

Comment: The downside of using `dynamic` is that you lose static type checking. If you ever decide to change your method names, method signatures or constructors, the compiler will not catch this for `dynamic` types.